# Docker compose only makes package-lock.json in app folder

Tags: docker

I have been trying to use docker to compile typescript code without having to install all the dependencies all over my laptop.

When I use this docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
    dodgeball-app:
        working_dir: /app
        image: 'node:lts'
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        tty: true
```

And I do

```
docker compose up -d
```

The only file in my app folder is a package-lock.json like this:

[The Filesystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir0sc.png)

So when I try to do `docker compose exec dodgeball-app npm install`, it says it cannot find the package.json file because it was never in that filesystem.
What I can do is `docker compose exec dodgeball-app npm --version` which does give me a correct version.

This is a file given to me by my school and it works for them, just not for me.

Comment: You havn't specified a command or entrypoint for the service. What are you expecting to happen? What do you mean *it works for them*? What exactly would "work" mean in this context and what is "not working" for you?

Comment: Sorry, il specify that in the post. What i mean by it works for them, is that i am trying to exec npm install on the container. but it cant find the package.json because there isnt any file that got copied over. And what i mean by work, is that they can do npm install and compile ts files in docker.

Comment: You are bindmounting the current directory into `/app`. Does your current directory contain a `package.json` file? The docker-compose file on it's own will not "do" anything. It will contain whatever project and/or files you mount or copy into it. Have you tried reading the documentation for docker to understand what it actually is or does? Please note that asking questions here on SO actually expects you do have done a fair amount of research at trying to solve your question. The lack of details in your question suggest you have not.

Comment: Yes it does, its just a full TS project with all the things it needs. The lack of details is because i have tried loads of stuff, watched countless of videos on why it wouldn't work and now i have no clue what to add into my post. And not a single video could explain me why its not working or what i am doing wrong.

Comment: The lack of details are due to the fact that you didn't add them to your question. Go take the [tour], read [ask] and have a look at how to make a [mre].

Comment: the question should also have node.js tag, but edit queue is full

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` command needs a `package.json` file (It has set of dependencies with not exact versions). `package-lock.json` (has set of exact versions) is generated by `npm install` from `package.json`. So either you need to have `package.json` in your directory to make your `exec` command work, either you can use `npm ci` command, which installs dependencies from `package-lock.json`

> docker compose exec dodgeball-app npm ci

This will solve 1st part of your problem, make dependencies install work.
But if your goal is compile something, you need to have it in your docker image (if it has only lock file now). You need to mount source codes or add them to docker using `ADD` command in `Dockerfile`.